# Multiple IP Cameras as Windows video sources?

Tags: c#, camera, directshow, media

Creating a video encoder app with multiple video sources. Is there a certain type of IP camera that can be used as a Windows video source (I.e. DirectShow) or a generic IP camera driver that can be used to connect both video and audio from a hardware camera?

Comment: What is your question here?  You are asking for a camera recommendation or what?

Answer (score 1):

To do video capture in directshow, you must acquire an IBaseFilter pointer to the video device, then add the filter to the graph.

You can get these IBaseFilter pointers for your cameras by enumerating the CLSID_VideoInputDevice category.

Getting audio follows the same procedure, this time though, you'll acquire the audio IBaseFilters by enumerating the CLSID_AudioInputDevice category.

I can post code to show how this is accomplished if you're interested, but I only have c++ code, I've never tried directshow coding with c#